# How to get UIStoryBoard segued UITabbarController reference

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have storyboard starting with `UINavigationController` then `UIViewController` and from this `UIViewController` just a segue to `UITabbarController`. I want this `UITabbarController` reference but from another view controller, How I can get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this with Storyboard ID. Set a Storyboard ID to TabBarController.

And here is the code that you can call it where you want.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"nameOfStoryboard" bundle:nil];


TabBarController * destViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TheIDOfTabBarController"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:destViewController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

If your segue goes from `UIViewController` to `UITabbarController` the `segue.destinationViewController` is actually your `UITabbarController`, so you can access it like that in the `UIViewController` class (remember to add segue identifier in the storyboard)

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"YOURSEGUEIDENTIFIER"]) { //<-- YOURSEGUEIDENTIFIER needs to match identifier you set up in storyboard
        UITabbarController *tvc = (UITabbarController*)segue.destinationViewController;
    } 
}
```

// I just moved code from comment area

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]; // <-- make sure Main match name of your storyboard
UITabbarController *tvc = [storyboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourIdentifierFromStoryboard"]; 
[tvc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
```

just remember to set up identifier for your table bar controller in storyboard.

Comment: @Grey Thanks for replying but I want to access it from another view controller.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what are you trying to do, please?

Comment: @Grey I want to modally present view controller but code is inside uitableviewcell subclass (which is wrong), but for now I want that uitabbarcontroller so I can present view controller.

Comment: I don't know I really understand what you are trying to do but try this: UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UITabbarController *tvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YOURIdentifierFromStoryboard"];
    [tvc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen]; just remember to set up identifier for your table bar controller in storyboard.